# Monitor no longer works

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport

I was having an issue with a monitor. It was working before but I was trying to move it to a different port. Specifically it has hdmi and vga ports and I was using it with vga. I then tried the hdmi but had a display port on my comp so I used an adapter.

It no longer would work. Specifically, what happens is that when I power it on it shows the screen for about 1/4 of a second then blacks out.

I thought it was the power supply(external) so I used a different one(same voltage, pin polarity, amp capacity, etc)... same issue.

I'm wondering if the display port adapter screwed something up? Anyone familiar with the hardware specification between hdmi and displayport and if a poorly designed hdmi adapter or monitor could cause a problem(such as an ic pin being fried).

I don't want to have to get a replacement of the monitor if it is fixable. It does not seem to be the power supply though and I seriously doubt it is the back light. It seems that for some reason it is going in turning off the display(it does not go in to sleep mode since the led does not change).

I'm about 98% sure that when I tried the display port is when it had problems. It could have been, actually, when I used the hdmi first. I went from vga to hdmi then display port. I'm not sure if I went to the display port because the hdmi failed to work(and hence the source) or if I went to display port to keep the hdmi port open for another monitor.

Any useful ideas that I could try out would be helpful.

There is probably a good chance that when messing with the hdmi or vga connectors that I caused a solder joint to lift since the monitor seems to be quite cheap.

Again, the monitor, when powering on, shows the scree(whatever is there) for about 1/4 of a second(very very quick, almost cannot see what it shows unless watching for it) then is black/dead. Turning off the power(which requires on to do some combinations of it's uni-button which means the internal logical is all functional) repeats the same issue exactly.

[It is possible that the power supply is bad and my bench supply cannot supply the 30W that is needed, I did another test on a 10ohm resistor and it seems the voltage is reduced significantly. It may be that the back light tries to kick in and the power simply isn't there so it dies and the voltage spikes back up. The external power supply of course is damn near impossible to get in to without tearing it up so if I try to fix it then it is not the problem then it would probably void the warranty... it's nice how all this works isn't it ;/ BTW, the monitor is new and I've used it for less than 2 weeks and even then I probably only have had it on for a total of 5 hours.]